# ArcGIS - Lines with different symbols and the same color ramp

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, color-ramp

i have a layer of lines which drives me crazy...

First i separate them in the tab multiple attributes, based on a value

blue lines = Symbol A (black)
red lines = Symbol B (black)
and so on...

Now i try to give them all the same color ramp, based on another value. But it doesnt't work right, ArcGIS doesnt use the color ramp i choose. Example i choose light blue too dark blue. When i close the Attributes the color is red...
How can i fix this?

Comment: I can't duplicate this problem. It gives me the ramp I select. I assume you are choosing "Variation by Color Ramp"? Can you add some further detail to your question spelling out the steps. Multiple Attributes allows Quantity by Category. Is one of your attributes numeric or not (it must be to do this)? I think you want to use "Categories" - "Unique Values Many Fields".

Comment: I select green to blue and its totaly mixed up red and yellow. White to black works fine, changing the color ramp manually doesnt help.
[link](http://i.imgur.com/5UpBGkr.jpg)

Comment: So... Do you want them to be symbolized like this example: "blue lines = Symbol A (black) red lines = Symbol B (black) and so on..." or do you want to use a color ramp?  You need to pick all the values you are using first, then symbolize the different combinations of value possibilities based on the fields you chose.  In other words...  Pick all the fields you will be using, and then create unique symbologies for each combination.

Comment: I want the different symboles AND i want to use different colors for a second attribute. Not possible? Or only with a new feature?

Comment: I see...  These are point features I'm assuming?  Add all of the fields you want to use, then pick symbols for each value, then highlight/select all the values and pick a color ramp.  You will have to do some manual choosing of symbols but this should get you there.  If it asks you to choose a Variation on either a color ramp or symbols size and you don't need this than just pick color ramp and change the jenks to 1.

Comment: No point, all are lines. [link](http://i.imgur.com/SHrR9HP.jpg)
It's a sewage water system. I need to see the different type of line (dirt or rain water) and in the second i want to see the year of construction in different colors.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly now, using Multiple Values does make sense. First select the field that has the "TYPE" information (Dirt or Rain).

[image]

You want to use line thickness to separate the line type (choose this first for your value field). No sense using a color since that is what your YEAR CONSTRUCTED is based on.

[image]

Then set the second field to use the Color Ramp (like I'm using with the ID_RTE_NO field)

[image]

That should do it!